# Autocomplete does not work when using Odoo / Openerp

Tags: ide, odoo, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm as my Odoo IDE. But for the reason of  no auto-complete function, it bring me coding trouble. So i wonder if there is a plugin that can provide auto-complete function or more convenient IDE?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome but sorry that we do not accept tools recommendations here.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] quite clearly says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: i don't really think this question is a bad question, i use odoo and auto-complete works well and it will if you point it to the right path where whatever library you want to use is

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse as Odoo IDE.
currently i am using eclipse as Odoo IDE, it's very easy to coding.

you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself using PyCharm for the most of my programming needs. The key pain points PyCharm solved for me where robust code intel tools, better Python application run and debug support, with traceback clicking. The development efficiency gained from these features is enough to migrate over, even though there are features I miss in Sublime Text. However, these editors sync files perfectly and I can always alt+tab switch to Sublime Text when I need to write some Restructured Text or Markdown.

I am looking forward for the upcoming contender Github’s atom.io editor which has the ease and flexibility of Sublime Text plugin system, but with better features, UI integration and big development-oriented company backing it up. Atom team is still working on getting the basic architecture together, so it might be few years until we see robust Python tools on Atom. I’d guess HTML, CSS and JavaScript support get there sooner, as they are building the Atom itself on CoffeeScript.